# Match words separated by comma in a line starting with a specific keyword

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I have the following text

```
type MyType1
type MyType2, MyType3
type MyType4,MyType5,MyType6, ...
NotMyType1, NotMyType2
```

How do I match all those comma-separated* words in lines starting with the keyword **type** so that what I only have at the end are

```
MyType1
MyType2
MyType3
MyType4
MyType5
MyType6
```

My initial attempt was to match all comma-separated words (https://regex101.com/r/mQDCgX/1)

```
(?<=[,])(\w+)(?=[,])|(?<=[\s,])(\w+)(?=[,]|$)
```

And then tried grouping it and used lookbehind to match **type**. However, it didn't work.

Note:
* The comma can also be surrounded by whitespace

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Try `(?:^type|\G(?!^)),? +\K(\w+)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/CV9jqu/1

Comment: You may use: `(?:\btype|(?!^)\G,)\h*\K[^,\s]*`

Comment: @revo that works! Today I learned \G and \K, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I encourage you to add your unsuccessful attempt(s) to your question so that we can post an answer. Currently it doesn't show any efforts on solving the problem by you.

Comment: I tested further, it seem's @revo's answer stops matching when words are strictly comma-separated, i.e. no whitespace in between. the \h* from anubhava's answer seems to handle it.

Comment: That's because you didn't have them in your question. It's not wrong. You just had to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

You may use this regex:

```
(?:\btype|(?!^)\G,)\h*\K[^,\s]*
```

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `(?!^)` is used to make sure we are not at the start
- `\K` is used to reset match info

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qikE5y/1)